# mod_rewrite newbie - is this correct?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

This is supposed to take any uri and send it as part of a query string to a script that will handle it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(css.php|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|json|xml|ico)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)?$ index.php?where=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm asking because it works on some servers and not on others. On some it just disregards the whole thing as if url rewriting is off, and on others it reports a bad request whenever .htaccess  with the above content is uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

BTH I would change this rule a bit:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css.php|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|json|xml|ico)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?where=$1 [QSA,L]
```

1. Added `\.` into RewriteCond pattern to ensure that it only works for files with such EXTENSIONS (otherwise pattern will also match files that have that text at the end i.e. `/something/mygif` <> `/something/my.gif`).
2. Replaced `(/)` by `/` in RewriteRule pattern -- it makes no difference in functionality but a bit lighter on resources.

---

**Back to main topic:**

- If it *"disregards the whole thing as if url rewriting is off"* then most likely .htaccess files are not supported/enabled (or it should have different name as configured by [AccessFileName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#accessfilename) directive: e.g. `AccessFileName ht.access`).

  To check it try placing some other directives into .htaccess and see if it works (like: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` or `DirectoryIndex index.php` etc).
- If it *"reports a bad request whenever .htaccess with the above content is uploaded"* then most likely these directives are not allowed to be placed in .htaccess (requires `AllowOverride All` or at least `AllowOverride FileInfo`; [see docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)) or mod_rewrite is not enabled.

  Check Apache's error log -- it should have entries mentioning this moment.